# Query result returns a single quotation mark

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query that returns a min, max, average and extra values. Sometimes in the extra_value results column it is returning a lone single quote ' which then goes onto break my code later in the application.

```
 SELECT MIN(IF (contact_timestamp <= '2018-09-24 12:10:37', contact_timestamp, NULL)) AS min_value,
     MAX(IF (contact_timestamp <= '2018-09-24 12:10:37', contact_timestamp, NULL)) AS max_value,
     AVG(IF (contact_timestamp <= '2018-09-24 12:10:37', MINUTE(contact_timestamp) * 60 + SECOND(contact_timestamp), NULL)) AS avg_value, 
     SUM(IF (contact_timestamp <= '2018-09-24 12:10:37', 1, 0)) AS count_value,
     CONCAT("'", GROUP_CONCAT(IF(contact_timestamp > '2018-09-24 12:10:37', id, NULL) SEPARATOR "' , '"), "'") AS extra_value
 FROM log_device_contact
 WHERE contact_timestamp > DATE_ADD('2018-09-24 12:10:37', INTERVAL -8 DAY)
```

Some times the results for the server results column are like this:

```
  '31504708' , '31504709' , '31504710' , '31504711' , '31504712' , '31504713' , '31504714' , '31504715' , '31504716' , '31504717' , '31504718' , '31504719' , '31504720' , '31504721' , '31504722' , '31504723' , '31504724' , '31504725' , '31504726' '
```

Sometimes they are not depending on what table i run the query on. How do I prevent the extra quote from ever happening no matter what?

Comment: Did you look at CONCAT_WS?

Comment: It's hard to tall without seeing the data that produced the results, but my best guess is that your input data is not what you expect it to be in some cases.

Comment: yeah could be. Even if i could trim of that single extra ' at the end of the string without affecting the rest of the single quotes would be fine

Answer (score 1):

```
CONCAT("'", GROUP_CONCAT(IF(contact_timestamp > '2018-09-24 12:10:37', id, NULL) SEPARATOR "' , '"), "'") AS extra_value
```

you are adding a final single quote in your CONCAT. What happens if you do like this?

```
CONCAT("'", GROUP_CONCAT(IF(contact_timestamp > '2018-09-24 12:10:37', id, NULL) SEPARATOR "' , '")) AS extra_value
```

without the last single quote? Does it happen again?

Answer (score 1):

Enclose each *value* in single quotes, rather than playing with the separator:

```
 GROUP_CONCAT( (CASE WHEN contact_timestamp > '2018-09-24 12:10:37'
                     THEN CONCAT('''', id, '''')
                END) SEPARATOR ',') AS extra_value
```

Note that there is no `CONCAT()` with `GROUP_CONCAT()` as an argument.  The only single quotes are added around ids.  The only commas are between values.

Comment: When it with your query modifications its still happening except the results are now like this: '31513250','31513251','31513252','31513253','31513254','31513255','31513256','31513257','31513258','31513259','31513260','31513261','31513262','31513263','31513264','31513265','31513266','31513267','31513268','31513269','31513270','31513271','     There is a comma before the extra quote

Comment: @user794846 . . . `group_concat()` would not be adding an extra comma.  The only quotes in this expression would be around `id`s.

Comment: Yes the group_concat length was limited to 1024 bytes and therefore was cutting it off.

Comment: You can set the max length using a system variable.

Comment: yes have fixed the issue. I added   $sql = "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 2000000"; to the code.